# how to use jedis for mass insertion of commands

Tags: redis, jedis

If I have create a file containing the following commands in the Redis protocol format:

SET Key0 Value0
SET Key1 Value1
...
SET KeyN ValueN

how can I use Jedis in my application to feed it to Redis?

Answer (score 6):

You can use pipelining. It allows to send multiple commands without waiting for individual responses, and get a unique response then. You will achieve better performance with this feature (you can expect x5 compared to a basic implementation).

Your implementation could look like this:

```
Pipeline p = jedis.pipelined();
for (int i=0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
    p.set(key[i], value[i]); 
}   
List<Object> results = p.syncAndReturnAll();
```

Comment: It's worth noting that pipelining, with Jedis, still sends the client->server commands individually, so you're not gaining anything at the TCP level.

Comment: Is there any way to find out the number of commands in the jedis pipeline? This would be helpful, if multiple threads add command to pipeline and another thread is periodically calling `sync`

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

The OP is looking for a solution to be run from Tomcat, I found out later. Using the raw Redis Protocol is not recommended here. Use Pascal's answer.

**/Edit**

I agree with Pascal that pipelining is a good way for almost-fastest mass insertion.
However, the OP is already talking about the Redis Protocol, which is even faster than pipelining.

It is however, **not** meant to be used from a Redis Client (like Jedis), but meant to be used directly on the server, in conjunction with redis-cli.

See [here](http://redis.io/topics/mass-insert) for more information.

Hope this helps, TW

Comment: Possible to send to redis-cli directly from my java app?

Comment: Or exec a bat file or something for redis-cli? I know how to run exec but not sure how to tie them together.

Comment: A bat file? Are you running redis-server on windows (MSopenTech)? Using an exec function should work fine, if you are on the server.

Comment: opps nope. i am using ubuntu. how should i feed it to redis-client using my java app running in tomcat in ubuntu?

Comment: Sadly, I'm can't help you there. Maybe post a generic question of evaluating a bash script in tomcat.
However, if you go for the pipelining route, you could use a [unix socket](http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf) instead of a TCP socket, which is a bit faster. It saves you the hassle of a bash script. If jedis doesn't support unix sockets, use TCP sockets.

Comment: I might add that, now I know the context of what you're trying to do, I __don't recommend__ this route. I wouldn't run an administrative task from a web server. Have you thought about concurrency? You don't need redis-cli, you can also open a raw socket and use the raw redis protocol there, outside of jedis. But in your case, that's not the way to go. Go for Pascal Le Merrer's answer. Sidenote: Using unix sockets is still a safe and valid route to improve performance. I'll edit my answer.